# Should a quotation starting with a vowel stay Capitalized?

Tags: quotations, vowels

I am using the Chicago Style Manual as a guide.
In doing so I have not made changes to quotations except where spelling is considered Old English - in these instances I sometimes have used [sic]. 
My question has to do with a quotation that starts with a capital letter but is part of an introductory sentence, for example:
“A person stands alone....”
Example of sentence introduction:
He said, “A person stands alone...”

Question: Should the vowel “A” be capitalized or lowercase?

Comment: Quoted sentences start with a capital. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Whether a letter is a vowel or consonant is essentially never why it would or wouldn't be capitalized in a particular instance.

Comment: With a quote from a written source, case is preserved: The note read: “a person stands alone ...” /  The note read: “A person stands alone ...” ( / The note read: “a person Stands Alone ...” ...). **BUT** are you here confusing something with the 'rule' about not capitalising the indefinite article in titles?

Answer (score 0):

I think, normally, it is not necessary to capitalise the first letter, be it a vowel or consonant, of the first word in a quotation, if it is not at the beginning of a sentence and the word is not a name.

Answer (score 0):

He said, "A person stands alone." This is your example and YES, the "A" is capitalized, as it is the start of the sentence that "he" said. This is a direct quote.